# Means in Numpy with tuples

Tags: python, numpy, tuples, mean

I have a list of tuples, and for some of the operations I need to do, I need to find the mean, but i'm having a problem that I don't quite understand.

```
# This works
weeks = [(1, 7),
         (8, 14),
         (15, 21),
         (22, 28),
         (29, 35),
         (36, 44)
         ]

# This doesn't work
np.mean(weeks[0][0], weeks[0][1])
```

I'm sure this is simple, but I dont understand the error: `AxisError: axis 7 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0`

Comment: Try `np.mean(weeks[0])`. The way you're using the function, the second element from the tuple is understood as the `axis` parameter (see [np.mean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert `weeks` to a numpy array and use the `mean` method:

```
np.array(weeks).mean()
```

Output:

```
21.666666666666668
```

You can also use the `axis` argument to calculate the mean of the 'rows' and 'columns':

```
print(np.array(weeks).mean(axis=0))
print(np.array(weeks).mean(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
array([18.5       , 24.83333333])
array([ 4., 11., 18., 25., 32., 40.])
```

Comment: I need the mean of each tuple.  Essentially what I'm doing is splitting the weeks in half for some other work that I need to do in my code.

Comment: I've updated it, use ```axis=1```

Comment: Please update your solution to include `np.array(weeks[0]).mean()` and I will mark that as correct.  That's exactly what I need.

Comment: so you only want the mean of the first row?

Comment: I needed the mean of each tuple individually.

Comment: yes, so that is given by ```np.array(weeks).mean(axis=1)```

Answer (score 1):

Not a numpy answer, but for a list of tuples you can use mean from the python `statistics` library, which takes a list or tuple as input and returns a mean.

```
from statistics import mean
weeks = [(1, 7),
         (8, 14),
         (15, 21),
         (22, 28),
         (29, 35),
         (36, 44)
         ]

print(mean(weeks[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want to find the mean of total elements or only of one specific axis?
for the first case try this

```
 weeks = [(1, 7),
     (8, 14),
     (15, 21),
     (22, 28),
     (29, 35),
     (36, 44)
     ]
  np.mean(weeks)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this?

```
for tup in weeks:
        print(np.mean(tup))
```